# Trying to access sharepoint site from shinyapps.io with authentication through Azure Active Directory

Tags: r, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, shinyapps

I am trying to develop a shiny app (which is hosted on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io)). The data resides on a company sharepoint site.
To authenticate users I am following allong the [Authenticating from Shiny vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureAuth/vignettes/shiny.html) by @Hong Ooi. This works when I use `resource <- "https://graph.microsoft.com"` instead of `resource <- "https://management.azure.com"`. I get a token, but am at a loss how to use this to connect to the sharepoint site (to retrieve the data from there).

It could be any or multiple of these:

- Settings in Azure Active Directory
- Settings for/in the sharepoint site
- The R code in the shiny app

Hope someone will have some pointers for me.